# CPU monitoring with samples using Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, wmi

i'm using the Get-WmiObject cmdlet, for monitoring the average CPU usage for servers without PowerShell installation, due to a security requirements.

```
$CPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -computername $computerName  | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average


$CPULoad = $($CPU.average)                                   

if ( $CPULoad -ge $ThresholdCPU ){                                          

Write-output "High CPU usage: $CPULoad % on $computerName" 

} 
Else {

Write-output "CPU usage on $computerName is normal: $CPULoad %" 

}
```

My script is working properly when the current CPU usage is above the CPU threshold iv'e manually set.

But i'm facing a lot of false alerts, due to the CPU usage spikes in the remote servers.

After reading the documentation of the cmdlet, i found that As opposed to the Get-Counter cmdlet, Get-WmiObject don't have some kind of a SampleInterval property.

Is there anyway to accomplish that using Get-WmiObject, so the if criteria will be true only after 3 valid samples?

Comment: If your script runs once and exits, then you will lose what it put into memory. If your script is configured that way, one way would be to create an output file (possibly a csv) that tracks the number of successive high CPU hits. You could also do the same tracking with a database. Once CPU checks out in the normal range, you can reset the counter in the file or database table.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, thanks. I’ve already accomplished that using external file and a while loop. But I really wanted to know if I missed something using this cmdlet..guess not

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a loop for a fixed number of times can do what you are after:

```
$maxAttempts = 3                                
for ($attempt = 0; $attempt -lt $maxAttempts; $attempt++) {
    $CPULoad = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computerName  | 
                Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average
    if ( $CPULoad -le $ThresholdCPU ) { break }
    # do nothing for x seconds and test CPU load again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

if ($attempt -lt $maxAttempts) {
    Write-output "CPU usage on $computerName is normal: $CPULoad %" 
}
else {
    Write-output "High CPU usage: $CPULoad % on $computerName" 
}
```

Comment: Theo, thanks. but as AdminOfThings wrote, my script runs once and exits, so all the data within $maxAttempts will lose what it put into memory.